# pytest 3.0.5 with cyrillic symbols

Tags: python, pytest, python-unicode

I have a problem with displaying test names with russian text in file paths in pytest-3.0.5.
When I run on **pytest==2.9.2** - everything is OK:

```
py.test -s -q --collect-only
```

Output:

```
test_card.py::test_graphic_card[/root/test_cases/files/Кредитная_карта_мир_41.png]
```

But when I try to run the same command on **pytest==3.0.5**:

```
py.test -s -q --collect-only
```

Output:

```
test_card.py::test_graphic_card[/root/test_cases/files/\xd0\x9a\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f_\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0_\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80_41.png]
```

What should I do to have py.test==3.0.5 display test names like displayed py.test==2.9.2?

Comment: This seems to be an implementation change in the newer version. You should consult the release notes and if they are not helpful contact the pytest team on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the **pytest** source code and found out, that in newest version of pytest
when tests are collected, they are processed with recently added function "***_escape_strings***".
In this function:

```
if isinstance(val, bytes):
    try:
        return val.encode('ascii')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:                     
        return val.encode('string-escape')
    else:
        return val.encode('unicode-escape')
```

I suppose this func is self-explained.
Finally, I've solved my problem decoding and unescaping of results in final test report, e.g.:

```
result = "/root/test_cases/files/\xd0\x9a\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f_\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0_\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80_41.png"
print result.decode('string-escape') 
Out: /root/test_cases/files/Кредитная_карта_мир_41.png
```